# showning images that are not stocked in web content - Glassfish 4

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

Hi I'm working on Glassfish 4, Java EE7. I want to show my images that I had saved in a folder named "Uploaded"  like this

```
                <image src="/uploads/image1.png" />
```

when I was working on tomcat7 I was changing the conf/server.xml by adding this line under the `<host>`

```
<Context docBase="c:/uploads" path="/uploads" />
```

I found that on Glassfish 3, the equivalent is to add an alternatedocroot to the glassfish-web.xml like this:

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=/c:/uploads" />
```

It didn't work for me on Glassfish 4 and I am wondering why this have changed in GF4.

I want to add the folder as a "virtual context" of the servletcontainer... Please if any one have idea.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from` represents the part of the full path that's exposed in the public (and thus visible in the URL). Basically, the composition of the `dir` and `from` should represent the full path.

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=/c:" />
```